# use module as a jar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-proguard

I have project created in android studio and a module in it too.

main project is **app** 
module name is  **jsondb**

i want to use `jsondb` module as a jar in my main project and even to distribute among the team members.

i have used retrofit , okhttp and other third party library in `jsondb` module. so whenever my team member use this `jsondb` they don't need to include dependencies related to retrofit or okhttp.

here is my current structure in which i am adding `jsondb` as a module. But i want to add it as a jar.

[image: current structure app & jsondb]

here are the dependencies involved in `app` and `jsondb`

[image]

[image]

here is my pro-guard settings for jsondb to obfuscate

```
-keep class com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.** { *; }
-keep @com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonObject class *
-keep class **$$JsonObjectMapper { *; }

-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class * { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**

-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.OkHttpClient.** { *; }

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

-keep public class com.jsondb.db.** { *; }
-keep public class com.jsondb.model.user.** {*; }
-keep public class com.jsondb.model.organization.** {*; }
-keep public class com.jsondb.model.master.** {*; }
-keep public class com.jsondb.model.complaint.** {*; }

-keep public class com.jsondb.db.model.** {*; }
-keep  public class com.jsondb.rest.RestApi {*** get*(***); *** callMasterData(***); *** registerRestCallback(***); }
-keep public interface com.jsondb.rest.RestApiCallback {*; }
```

i tried added `aar` file into another project as follows

[image]

here you can see i have to add `retrofit` and `retrofit2 converter` in new project. if i dont add them in gradle then it shows `NoClassDefinationFound` for retrofit.

Comment: down voters have a courtesy to explain the reason for the same

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to share a module among your different projects.

The common way of doing it is to create an Android Library project. The output is going to be an .aar file which is the jar of the android world :).

Then you just wrap your calls to not call retrofit directly, something like this:

```
  public interface UserWebService {
    @POST("customer")
    User register(@Body String name);
  } 

  //Wrapper class
  public class UserDao{
    public User getUser(String name){
       //userWebService.register is the actual retrofit call
       return userWebService.register(name);
    }
 }
```

and in your non library module:

```
userDao.getUser("Fred")
```

Some Reference link:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Comment: i had refereed to this tutorial only `Vogella` :)  , i did it the same but the issue is the third party libraries. i have added them as a dependency in `jsondb` but still its giving `NoClassFound` error when other team member import it

Comment: NoClassFound for which class?

Comment: you can't use a dependency directly from a library project, you need to wrap it into your library's method

Comment: i tried that too but still same class not found issues are still there `                                                        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106430/discussion-between-hunt-and-jbarat).